# On WebView2, how can I cancel NavigationStarting event?

Tags: c#, .net, webview2

Using WebView2 version 1.0.1150.38 which is the latest at time of post.

I'm using WebView2 as a .EML (email) file viewer. When a user clicks on a hyperlink, I need to use `Process.Start` to open the link, so that web links open in the default browser, and the attachments open with the default applications.

I've subscribed to the `NavigationStarted` event and can use `Process.Start` as intended, however I need to stop the WebView2 control from also browsing to the URL or starting the download.

```
private void CoreWebView2_Navigate(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    if (loaded == true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hyperlink clicked: " + e.Uri);
        Process.Start(e.Uri);
        //Stop navigation
    }
}
```

I don't see a method to do this on this event. I previously used `CoreWebView2DownloadOperation` which does support the `Cancel` method but this isn't ideal as I need to interrupt all navigation operations.

Comment: Just realised I can use `webView2.Stop()`, but I don't know if this is the best practice. It appears to do what I need however. Leaving question open incase there's a better way.

Comment: Set `e.Cancel = true;` inside `NavigationStarted` event.

Comment: @PoulBak Thanks. That works. Strange that for `DownloadStarting` it's a method that can be used like `e.Cancel();` but this one is a property. Add it as an answer if you wish.